# Converting PDF to Tiff using PDFBox 2.0.14 on linux font issue

Tags: java, linux, pdfbox

I am having an issue while converting PDF to Tiff on linux system(Windows is working fine), I feel few fonts are not loaded/found.

I am attaching the original PDF file and output Tiff file. You can see the difference in the fonts of PDF and output tiff.

[Original PDFfile](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kk8pUyo2ExJRI_iizGR6-ceQRkvveSXb)

[Converted Tiff](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_0fTf8GKBHNiPOzjtERSEALdmhjTts_a)

You can clearly see the difference in 2 files. Is there any font which is missing on the linux(same is working fine with other PDF tools)?

Comment: Please update to 2.0.15, and share any log messages you get. Consider also sharing your .pdfbox.cache file. (in your user directory)

Comment: Sorry, It was my mistake. I was using 1.8.* version.

Comment: The 1.8 version had many flaws with fonts. Which is why that was much improved in 2.0.*.